# Android: How to pass all the data from RecyclerView adapter to NewActivity by clicking button outside of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I want to pass prices (without titles) from RecyclerView to NewActivity and then display them sorted by clicking on the button. I've got a problem with passing all of the prices  to NewActivity by clicking on one button (button is under RecyclerView)

```java
 class MyAdapter(val context: Context, val costs: List<Cost>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val cos = costs[position]
        holder.title.text = cos.price.toString()
        holder.price.text = cos.price.toString()

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, convertVie: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.one_item,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(myView)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return costs.size
    }
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
        var price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price) as TextView
}
```

```java
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)




        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)


        var costs = ArrayList<Cost>()
        costs.add(Cost(3.00))
        costs.add(Cost(5.00))
        costs.add(Cost(1.00))
        costs.add(Cost(7.00))

        val adapter = MyAdapter(this, costs)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
```

Comment: Create a fun in adapter class `getList` or `getdata` which returns you a list of cost objects and send it to newActivity and received it from `intent.extra` function and apply sort on it in this way `listName.sort()`. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fetch result for adapter

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
List<Cost> costs;
.. some other code

// Return total cost of items inside list
public float getTotal(){
float total = 0f;

for(Cost cost : costs)
     total+=cost.price;
return total;
}
```

For sorting list by clicking button outside Recyclerview

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

       MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter)recyclerview.getAdapter();// fetching adapter
       Collections.sort(adapter.getItems(),new Comparator<Cost>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Cost c1, Cost c2) {
            return c1.price - c2.price;// sort item in list
        }
    });
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// update list

  }
});
```

adapter.getItems()

```
public List<Cost> getItems(){return costs;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in your adapter, getList() that returns the list of just prices, I'm not sure about sorting in kotlin so you'll have to find that but you'll then be able to call adapter.getList() from a button in the same activity to get all the items, then you can pass them between activities in a few ways, you can use a bundle and pass it in an intent if the list is very small, you can implement parcleable on the cost object if it has a lot of fields, you can pass it to a view model and access it from another class, you can create an interface and pass it between anything that way, or you can convert it to a JSON string using the gson library, there are numerous ways depending on your use case going forward

Answer (score 0):

```
You should provide some repository for your data. Singleton instance that will store your data, and you would retrieve from it in any activity you want.
Basic schema for example:
class Repo{
    private List<String> mData;
}

View (Ani fragment or activity). You just need call Repo.getInstance().getList();
And it won`t be depends on lifecyle of any android component.

P.S. Use Android Architecture Components https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using kotlin and your costs object is instantiated before settings adapter to recyclerview, you can just call

`costs.sortedBy { it.price }.map { it.price }` that would give you an lsit of Int which you could pass into your intent with `writeIntArray`. (you might need to cast it by `.toArray()`) and then you can easily get it from your activity's intent

Answer (score -2):

You can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to convert the whole list to json string by passing it to intent from current activity & then restore it back to list on receiving activity.

Current Activity:

1. Gson gson = new Gson();
2. String json = gson.toJson(list);

Note: Pass the json string to intent.

Receiving Activity:
Note: Receive the json string from intent.

1. Gson gson = new Gson();
2. Type type = new TypeToken>() {}.getType();
   List list = gson.fromJson(json, type);

Comment: It seems to be bad choice. What if list is big?

Comment: I think this will be the easiest & shortest method without worrying about big list to pass data as string.

Comment: You should worrying  about big list, you cannot build system that depends of list size. I would suggest build a system from ground with proper architecture. Maybe the easiest approach is mvvm + repository pattern + android arch components, that well explained on https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture and on many  another related resources. Really  you`ll make your life more easy.

Comment: Yes you’re right but it depends on both positive aspects & negative ones before deciding the pattern to follow singleton or this. Allocating a memory when needed or always needed is also plays a part.

Comment: In repository you can control life of your objects. Last my work is player, there are a lot of track from different resources (local disc, services like soundcloud/spotify/dropbox/youtube ), i use this approach there and it is really helps a lot.

Comment: Yes building something like a media player really does require singleton instances as we need to keep the list alive throughout the application.